# Problem using npm of chart.js in django Project

Tags: javascript, django, npm, chart.js

I tried to use Chart.js in my Django project , when I Use NPM package it's not working but when I use CDN  It work Perfectly

char.js version 3.9.1

here is my index.html file on my project

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
{#    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>#}
    <script type="application/json" src="/node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

my console error in browser is :

```
(index):17 Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined
    at (index):17:17
```

I tried to use chart.min.js in my script but not working.
I also Try previous version of charj.js but still not working.
I also copy code on CDN and put it locally on project but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must Use static path so django can server js file

```
Project Name
   app Name
       static
           js 
           css
           img
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Django renders the html based on what you declare in the context object in your views in Python. Django doesn't know anything about NPM, NodeJS and the `node_modules` folder.

Generally when you use npm to install packages is beacuse you are using them in a NodeJS project that in the end is gonna be converted in a vanilla JS file without dependencies, to be hosted.

That's why install Chart.js with npm it's not gonna work, because it will be stored in a node_modules folder, and Django doesn't know what to do with that. But when you use a cdn you are almost embedding the dependency inside the html, and now it can be referenced in all the JS scripts after it declaration.

I hope that explanation will help you, if there is something that you think that is no well explained, please, let me know.